# react custom anchor component w/ do something before click functionality issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

### React Component (Custom Anchor)

```ts
import React from 'react';

class Anchor extends React.Component {
  onClick = (event) => {
    // -----------------------------
    // send Google Analytics request 
    // -----------------------------

    if (this.props.onClick) {
      this.props.onClick(event);
    }
  }

  render () {
    return <a {...this.props} onClick={this.onClick} />;
  }
}

export default Anchor;
```

#### Example

```ts
const test1 = <Anchor href="https://www.google.com" />
//  not work - did not send Google Analytics request - but open "href"
```

Easy solution you think? Just add `event.preventDefault()` to `onClick` function? Ok imagine we added that...

```ts
const test2 = <Anchor href="https://www.google.com" onClick=((e) => console.log(e)) />
```

it send Google Analytics request because we added `event.preventDefault()` but it did not open `href`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `event.preventDefault()` in your onClick. Then do your request wait for response and set your href via `window.location.href="https://www.google.com";`

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" onClick={e =>{ e.preventDefault(); console.log("do your stuff..."); window.location.href="https://www.google.com";  }}>test</a>
```

Or am I missing something?